# How to run some exe file from another computer in a domain C#

Tags: c#

how can i command to run file.exe file from another computer in my domain with C#

I know System.Diagnostic.Process.Start but its starting in my computer.
How can i use it for "192.168.100.2" ip addressed computer for running an exe file from my comp with a command? I know TCP/Socket programming but else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), a part of [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx), can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a UI for the .exe you can use WMI to start a process remotely. I haven't got code to do it here but [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx) looks like it would work.

Answer (score 1):

one easy way is to have the remote computer listening to some kind of event, this could be message queues, remoting(port listening) , web services/http.

once it listen to the event the host computer will need to start the process itself, this will ensure security in the host computer since it will run under some local credentials and policies.

Answer (score 0):

You may Share a folder containing the .exe on your computer within the domain and use telnet to get a command line on the other computer to run the program. Nothing specific to C#/.NET however.